# how to solve below native script code sharing app creation error?

Tags: angular2-nativescript, nativescript-codesharing

i am beginner to nativescript and i am getting the error while creating the nativescript angular code sharing  new app using CLI

i am trying ng new -c=@nativescript/schematics ns-oys --shared --style=scss command to create new application.

gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:149:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:149:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)\n    at F ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)\n    at E ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)\n    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16\n    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5\n    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5\n    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:149:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:149:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:149:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)\n    at F ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)\n    at E ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)\n    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16\n    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5\n    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5\n    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:149:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:149:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "E:\anup\programFile\node\node.exe" "F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd F:\Work\ns\ns-oys\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.3.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Answer (score 1):

Update angular cli using command npm i -g @angular/cli and the command started working.

Comment: Or First uninstall currently installed cli using `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`. Then clear npm cache using `npm cache clean or npm cache verify (if npm version > 5)` and finally install latest using `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`.